# SimpleXML framework: How to convert a non-standard basic type representation?

Tags: java, xml, simple-framework

I am trying to convince SimpleXML to convert my Java objects to and from XML. I have a (seemingly) simple problem but I have now already wasted substantial time searching a description or an example for doing the following:

The XML format that I need to read or generate contains integer values that define colors and which are represented as hex integers (but without a leading "0x", same as in HTML or in misc. Android .xml files), i.e. red="ff0000", blue="00ff00", green="0000ff", etc.

My XML contains elements like:

```
<SomeObject name="foobar" checkedColor="123456" flaggedColor="FEDCBA" ... />
```

The corresponding Java class reads:

```
public class SomeObject 
{
    @Attribute
    String name;
    @Attribute #######
    int checkedColor;
    @Attribute #######
    int flaggedColor;
    // ...
}
```

I marked the two attributes I am talking about here with ####### above. The color values should be of type "int".

How do I teach SimpleXML that these value are represented as hex-string and how to convert them?
What transformer or converter or whatever do I need to write so that these int values are converted to/from hex-strings as shown and  what do I have to annotate in the above code to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Use a Transform, see the documentation below

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/transform/Transform.html

Comment: I saw that part of the tutorial, but - alas - that doesn't fly because one can not define a "implements Transform<int>" (since int is a basic type).

Comment: I also tried to define a class "HexInt extends Integer" ,  but that didn't work since Integer is a final class. :-(  
Any suggestions how to "trick" around such restrictions?

Furthermore: wouldn't such a Transformer then be used for ALL attributes that are int's? How can one restrict this to be used for these two specific int-attributes only, but not for others, e.g. if I had a width or height attribute, where I would want to use "normal" (i.e. decimal) integers, not hex-numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I was finally able to implement what I want by defining a type "HexInt" which looks as follows

```
public class HexInt
{
    private int value;

    public HexInt(int value) {
        setValue(value);
    }
    public HexInt(String value) {
        setValue(value);
    }

    protected int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    protected void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
    protected void setValue(String value) {
        setValue(Integer.parseInt(value, 16));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return Integer.toHexString(getValue());     
    }
}
```

and defining the corresponding attributes as

```
...
@Attribute(required=false)
protected HexInt checkedcolor;
@Attribute(required=false)
protected HexInt flaggedcolor;
...
```

plus defining a Matcher which for HexInt-s provides a corresponding Transformer that properly converts these values to and from strings.

But what I hate about this solution is, that I not only had to annotate my java code to achieve that result but actually had to use special, representation-specific classes, even though from the program logic there would be absolutely no need to define a special class containing only an int, just because I want to serialize these two fields in a special way. IMHO following an aspect oriented spirit the internal representation ("int") should be defined in the basic Java-code and that code should be agnostic of how the data gets represented when externalized. 
The external representation on the other hand (i.e. whether I want to represent int-value as a decimal or hexadecimal string) should be defined in the annotations ONLY (plus supportive classes like Matcher and Transformer) but *not* in the basic Java code.

Is there really no way in the SimpleXML-framework to keep these different aspects more cleanly separated?